# Why is ==0 needed, when i delete it i get error "The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean"

Tags: java

Ok so i was looking at someones code for a leap year checker i was wondering why did he/she put ==0 right after year % 4. And also why is modulo(%) used here.. If you use a caculator to find a leap year you would need to use division(/) for a example 2000 / 4 = 500 so it will make 2000 a leap year..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapChecker {
    public void Check(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type a year: ");
        int year = input.nextInt();

        if (year % 4 ==0 && (year % 100 !=0)){
            System.out.println("The year is a leap year.");
        }else if (year % 4 ==0 && (year % 100 ==0) && (year % 400 ==0) ){
            System.out.println("The year is a leap year.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The year is not a leap year.");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         LeapChecker leap = new LeapChecker();
        leap.Check();
    }
}
```

Comment: So if you use a calculator for 2001 what do you get?

Comment: because the modulus operator is equivalent to `a - (a / b)`, so if it returns 0 (hence the `== 0`, the a is divisible by b

Comment: Unlike C and C++, Python and others, Java does not treat zero and non-zero integers as false and true boolean values, respectively. This is A Good Thing™.

Comment: A year is leap year if it is multiple of 400 or multiple of 4 but not multiple of 100. So condition 1 in your code is checking for whether year is multiple of 4 and not multiple of 100. By using modulus operator we are finding out remainder and this remainder should be zero in order to be divisible by 4. That is why year % 4 == 0 condition is there.

Comment: @Jennifer thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply becuase `year % 4` evaluates to 0 if `year` is evenly dividable by 4 (year 2012, 2016, 2020, ...)

`9 % 4` equals 1 since there will be a remaineder of 1 after the division of integers. `10 % 4` equals 2, `11 % 4` equals 3, `12 % 4` equals 0

Answer (score 2):

The result of `year % 4` is an `int`.

The `&&` operator (and `||`) is defined only for boolean operands, or operands which can be automatically converted to boolean (which means `Boolean` can be used too).

From the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23):

> Each operand of the conditional-and operator must be of type boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs.

There is no implicit conversion from `int` to `boolean` (unlike other languages such as C, C++, Python etc). This is a good thing: it forces you to be explicit about conversions.

As such, you have to do the int to boolean conversion yourself - for example, using a relational operator like `==`, `>=`, `<` etc, or by passing the `int` to a method which returns a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

when you use calculator for division by 4, you know if you get a integer answer, then the year is divisible by 4, similarly in programming languages, modulo operator is used to get the remainder after division, if the remainder is zero (remainder == 0), then the number is divisible by 4.

And, && operator is one which checks all the CONDITIONS surrounding it are true, but yes conditions. It must be surrounded by conditions or technically boolean (true/false) values or literals. And values returned by modulo i.e. 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 (in this case) are not boolean values.

Comment: see Andy Turner's comment to understand better

Comment: i hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

`year % 4 ==0` this will return a `boolean` value and year % 4 will return an int value. For the if condition you need to put a `boolean` expression.

And `year % 4` will give you the remainder after you divide the year. So here you are checking if it's equal to `0`. In programming its the way to check if that number is divisible by `4`